# Connecting 2 cellular Routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I want to connect to 4G routers over the cellular network, so client A connects to Router A which has 4G SIM card which is connected over cellular network to another 4G SIM card installed on Router B and client B connected to it.

I am using **Openwrt**, how can I accomplish this? What is the required router configuration and packages assuming that the Telecom company configured the 2 SIMs card and assigned IP addresses to them correctly and they are connected ( Ping from SIM A to SIM B succeeded) but no data transfer between Site A and Site B?

Comment: You may need VPN and VPN addressing upgrade from both ISPs.  I have one VPN upgrade for my one Cellular card.